# How to create pairs from a text file that is a number and the word that precedes that number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text

I am working on a new project and the team I was assigned to is all Python. I am not that proficient in Python so I thought I'd turn to stackoverflow for help. My portion of the project is to Write a program that reads a text file and creates pairs from everything it finds in the file that is a number and the word that precedes that number. The only thing I have done is get the program to read the text file and print the whole thing. But I do not know how to get it to spit back pairs that is a number and the word that precedes it. Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Text file contents example:

```
I have 3 apples.
The apples were very good.
I ate 7 bananas.
The bananas were just as good.
```

Desired output:

```
have, 3
ate, 7
```

My code so far:

```
in_file = open("FILE.txt", "rt")  
contents = in_file.read()       
in_file.close()                  
print(contents)
```

### (LOGIC THAT SENDS BACK PAIRS THAT IS A NUMBER AND THE WORD THAT PRECEDES IT)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give an example of the format of your file, as it is quite hard to help you if there aren't enough details.

Comment: do you have any sample data to help the community address correctly your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your edit greatly improved your question: congratulations. I edited your question a little more. But just what do you mean by "get back pairs"? Do you want an output text file that looks like the part of your question now? Do you mean you want a function to return a list of tuples of size 2? Also, by "number" do you mean a string of consecutive decimal digits representing an integer, or do you want to include numbers with a decimal point or other kinds of numbers?

Comment: What if the numeric string is the first one on a line? Do you want the last word from the previous line?

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex:

```
import re

with open('FILE.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    contents = in_file.read()

pairs = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+(\d+)', contents)
print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
[('have', '3'), ('ate', '7')]
```

Demo for the pattern: https://regex101.com/r/bZzlJs/1

If you wanted an `int` instead of a string for the number, you can do

```
pairs = [(word, int(num)) for word, num in re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+(\d+)', contents)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
result = []
def is_num(text):
    try:
        float(text)
        return True
    except:
        return False
with open('myfile', 'rw') as nf:
    lines = nf.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line_list = line.split()
        for idx, item in enumerate(line_list):
            if is_num(item):
                result.append([item, line_list[idx-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

So i take the file read all of the lines as one string. replace "\n" with a space
then I can split it up into each word by splitting at each space. then by iterating through the split words any time is a positive integer I print it and its predecessor word. (I handle integers at the beginning of lines but not the beginning of files)

```
with open("FILE.txt","r") as f:    
    s = f.read()
    s = s.replace("\n"," ")
    s = s.split(" ")
    for k in range(s.length()):
        if(s[k].isdigit()):
            print(s[k-1],s[k])
```

NOTE: isdigit only works is the number is positive and no decimal is present use try except to handle decimals